# Styling table issue

Tags: html, css, css-tables

So I want table to have borders only below each row.

```
td{

    border-bottom-style: solid;}
```

But, between columns, there is visible border break. I don't get how can I remove that?

Comment: Please post some example code or create a fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Adrift/LSNR7/

Answer (score 3):

Use the border collapse in your CSS.

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use

```
table {
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

or, if that is not an option (it could cause more problems than it solved in earlier versions of IE), you can proceed as follows...

```
table {
   border-spacing:0;
}
```

Take your pick!

Comment: Who cares about earlier versions of IE?))) It's some kind of extreme perfectionism

Comment: You'd be surprised how many people are stuck with IE8, because they hang on to Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below :

```
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```